# Ruby IDE (from a Visual Studio background)

Tags: ruby, ide

For a university I was advised to learn Ruby before starting. I have a strong .NET background (with C#) and would like to find an IDE for Ruby. I'm currently very familiar with/used to VS2010 and VS2012.

- Which IDE has the most similarities with Visual Studio?
- Is there a certain prominent IDE that is far better than it's competitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find [RubyMine by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) to be the closest to Visual Studio that I've found. It's paid, comes with support, and is built off of Eclipse (I think).

If you're interested in using a text editor, I've found [Sublime Text 2](http://sublimetext.com/) to be a very nice choice. I used to use TextMate all the time, but I'm gradually switching to Sublime Text.

Comment: No, JetBrains RubyMine is not built on Eclipse (which is the major competitor to JetBrains), it's built on JetBrains IDEA.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks Jörg, they look very similar to me so I tend to assume it's a fork of Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

> Which IDE has the most similarities with Visual Studio?

[Visual Studio](http://SapphireSteel.Com/Products/Ruby-In-Steel/), of course!

> Is there a certain prominent IDE that is far better than it's competitors?

[RubyMine](http://JetBrains.Com/ruby/) is sometimes cited as the best one. Personally, I haven't used it, so I can't comment on it. RubyMine is basically a lean (i.e. without the Java support) version of IntelliJ IDEA with the IDEA Ruby Plugin pre-installed.

I have always used the NetBeans Ruby Plugin and have been somewhat satisfied with it.

Now, if you have experience with IDEs for other dynamic languages such as Lisp or Smalltalk, then all of the Ruby IDEs, whether that be RubyMine, Eclipse RDT, Eclipse DLTK/Ruby, Ruby in Steel, RadRails or 3rd Rail, or "IDEs" such as Vim, Emacs, TextMate, Sublime, etc. will feel like primitive stone age tools in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an IDE called visualruby which works like Visual Basic.  You build your forms visually using the glade interface designer.

Take a look at

http://visualruby.net

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine is the closest to Visual Studio, and is a great way to transition into writing Ruby code. Unfortunately, once you join a team that *doesn't* use an IDE you're going to have a hard time keeping one happy.

IDE's usually require "hints" about the code and with Ruby's dynamic nature it gets really easy to write code the IDE can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) have plugins for Ruby, between the two I personally prefer Netbeans, but I only use them for Java programming. For Ruby I use Vim which you can customize into whatever needs you have.

Comment: Eclipse RubyDT is a good choice for large Rails project, but for smaller project is a bit too chuncky.

Comment: I find both Netbeans and Eclipse as too bulky an IDE to work with any interpreted language honestly, I do all my coding in vim, except for C#, Java and Objective-C

Comment: Yes I use vim or gedit. There were request that Ruby should have an IDE like python, but many people just think it is not necessary so not much effort into that.

Answer (score 0):

All the people I know use a text editor for Ruby (at my company either Vim, or Sublime Text 2). Not that Ruby programmers can't use an IDE, but they generally don't.

If you're looking to learn Ruby, might be worth trying it out without a full fledged IDE.

Comment: I second this, you have plenty of resources on the net to learn to use a good text editor, for example: https://www.shortcutfoo.com

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Visual Studio 2010 installed (seems to always be installed as part of other Microsoft Tools) Ruby In Steel 2.0 is definitely worth a look. Sure, it's using an older shell but it's fast and familiar.